# german tank problem — frequentist answer derivation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

I have a question on this famous problem called the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem).

Assuming tanks are assigned sequential serial numbers starting with 1, suppose that four tanks are captured and that they have the serial numbers: 19, 40, 42 and 60. What's your best guess for $N$, the the total number of tanks that are produced?

In [this article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/03/frequentist-german-tank-problem/), deriving the frequentist approach for this problem, the author starts by finding the expected value of not $N$, but the sample max in terms of $N$. Then, he rearranges the formula in terms of $N$, and that's the estimate. According to the Wikipedia, this method not only gives an unbiased estimator, but the minimum-variance unbiased estimator. Why?

Comment: The sample maximum is a minimal sufficient statistic here.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Uniform_distribution) discusses just this point